# VBA to show new line in body of email in outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add new line in body of email and used `vbNewLine` and `vbCrLf`  but not able to success. Please advise as to how can I add new line in body of email. All the content in body of email is reflecting in one line.

```
On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ".com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .HTMLBody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A14").Value & vbCrLf & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A15").Value & " " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A16").Value & vbCrLf & vbNewLine & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send

    End With
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change the `.HTMLBody` line:

```
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
        .To = ".com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .HTMLBody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A14").Value & chr(10) & _
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A15").Value & " " & _
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A16").Value & chr(10) & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send
End With
```

The `chr(10)` should make the trick (adds a new line). Note that `_` is just to split the vba code in multiple lines to improve readability.

HTH ;)